# Way to parseInt without try-catch in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way to try to convert to int a string that can be or not an integer?
Integer.parseInt(String value) will work well with "25" or "019" but not with "hello" or "8A".
In Java 8, we have optional values, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<Integer> optionalResult = functionThatReturnsOptionalInteger();
    Integer finalValue = optionalResult.orElse(0);
    System.out.println(finalValue);
}

public static Optional<Integer> functionThatReturnsOptionalInteger() {
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[0];
    return Stream.of(ints).findAny();
}
```

You do not need to check nulls, because the `Optional` wrapper expose useful methods to deal with this kind of situations.

But if you want to `parseInt` a string, that can be null, or does not contains a valid integer, the solution is the same as always:

```
public static Integer parseIntOrDefault(String toParse, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(toParse);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

How can improve this with Java 8 features, why Integer.parseInt() has not been **overloaded** to **return an Optional** in case of bad argument? (Or just add a new method Integer.parseIntOptional() to Integer wrapper)

Comment: That would not allow old code to compile on the new version.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overwritten"? Do you mean replaced, or just overloaded (added an `Optional`-variant additional to the existing `parseInt` method (I know an overload doesn't work here))

Comment: @Felk, yes, sorry, overloaded!

Comment: I find it more intuitive for Integer.parseInt("hello") to throw a `NumberFormatException` than to return `Optional.empty()`

Comment: Alright. As a side note: an overload wouldn't work here because you can't overload by having a different return type only. Adding said `Optional`-variant would have required a different method name. Doesn't change the core question though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike other answers *that are now deleted*, I don't think this really has to do with Java being backwards-compatible.

Because an empty `Optional` represents a **value that is absent**, it would mean that the method actually **worked** but no results are returned.

However, parsing `hello` as an integer will not work and has to throw an exception, because **it is an error** rather than an empty result. Keep in mind that `NumberFormatException` extends `IllegalArgumentException`.

More generally speaking, `Optional` was made for **dealing with possibly absent values** (instead of using `null` for that), and not for error handling. Also, `Optional` doesn't provide any way to know what is the error and why there is one.

Comment: I totally agree on not misusing `Optional` in case of an error.

Comment: I agree that the semantics of `Optional` don't fit the usecase, but I also see the practical advantages of using `Optional` class. I think something like a `Result<T>` class representing either a return value or an error, similarly to how Rust handles it, would give the same advantages while having fitting semantics.

Comment: I'd argue that `Optional` wasn't made for dealing with possible `null` values per se, but to replace the practice of using null values to express possibly absent values.

Comment: @Felk "_[...] express possibly absent values_": you're right, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 16):

There doesn't exist anything like this in the standard library afaik, but you can write a method that parses a `String` into an `Optional<Integer>` like this:

```
public static Optional<Integer> parseInt(String toParse) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(toParse));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonathan's answer actually contains a valid reason as to why a method like this might not exist in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

Without a try-catch and still returning an Optional - you could do

```
Optional<Integer> result = Optional.ofNullable(input)
    .filter(str -> str.matches("-?\\d+"))
    .map(Integer::parseInt);
```

**EDIT**: Regex updated to support negative numbers

**WARNING**: As pointed out in the comments, will still throw a RuntimeException if the parsed String turns out to be outside the range of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: This will reject actually correct negative numbers while at the same time may still throw an exception if the numerical value is out of range…

Comment: You are right sir - I edited the regex to accept negative numbers. As for the range, it depends on the usage scenario - very rarely do we have very big numbers - it is up to the asker to decide if he is OK with a RuntimeException on out of range inputs

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan while you have your own opinions, I prefer this style now especially since Java 8 came along. Try to read up on functional programming constructs, and avoidance of returning nulls. It encourages better software engineering.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t want to speculate why such method does not exist, but if you like neither, perform a pre-test nor catch an exception, you need a re-implementation, e.g.

```
public static OptionalInt parseInt(String s) {
    if(s.isEmpty()) return OptionalInt.empty();
    final int len = s.length(), limit;
    final boolean negative;
    int i = 0;
    switch(s.charAt(0)) {
        case '-':
            i=1;
            if(len==1) return OptionalInt.empty();
            negative = true;
            limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            break;
        case '+':
            i=1;
            if(len==1) return OptionalInt.empty();
            // fall-through
        default:
            negative = false;
            limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    final int limitBeforeMul = limit / 10;
    int result = 0;
    for(; i < len; i++) {
        int digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        if(digit < 0 || result < limitBeforeMul || (result *= 10) < limit + digit)
            return OptionalInt.empty();
        result -= digit;
    }
    return OptionalInt.of(negative? result: -result);
}
```

This basically does the same as `Integer.parseInt`, but returns an empty `OptionalInt` for invalid strings instead of throwing an exception…

As you might notice, the hardest part is to handle numbers close to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` resp. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Guava library provides a helper method to do this: Ints.tryParse(String).It runs `null` when the string is not parsable. You can checkout the [documentation](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/) it can be written like this.

If you just want to do something with the result you could do it in a single expression

```
Uni.createFrom()
  .item(() -> Integer.parseInt(toParse))
  .onFailure().recoverWithItem(defaultValue)
  .subscribe().with(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Or create a method like the one intended

```
    public static Integer parseIntOrDefault(String toParse, int defaultValue) {
        Integer[] toReturn = new Integer[]{null};
        Uni.createFrom()
           .item(() -> Integer.parseInt(toParse))
           .onFailure().recoverWithItem(defaultValue)
           .subscribe().with(i -> toReturn[0] = i);
        return toReturn[0];
}
```

This solution adds a library, but the lib is not specific to handle this problem. It uses reactive programing, futures, callbacks and a fluent API and proves to be flexible enough to solve this problem.